# Parser Error when trying to read csv File with pandas on jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, opencsv

Hey community im new to coding and as a job task they asked me to read a csv file. I used the commands:

```
import pandas as pd 
dataset = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UDG-United-Digital-Group/frontend-junior-code-challenge-1/master/Artikel.csv")
```

And after that second command I get the Parser error.

I would be very thankful for any help I am really hoping on landing this job.

Comment: hereares the error messages https://paste.pics/FI2DK and https://paste.pics/FI2E3

Comment: include the error as text in your original post, not as an image

Comment: By default, CSV files are expected to use commas as field separators.  But that file appears to use semicolons instead.

Answer (score 1):

The csv in question seems to be `;` (semicolon) delimited. So, specify that as a parameter when calling `read_csv`

```
pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UDG-United-Digital-Group/frontend-junior-code-challenge-1/master/Artikel.csv", delimiter=";")
```

More info available at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html